# Has the Stack Overflow "Top Questions" list changed - dramatic decrease in questions shown?

Tags: discussion

Today, for some reason, the number of questions "Active" on the Stack Overflow "Top Questions" list for my watched tags has decreased by ~90% or more. The tags I watch are:

```
[assembly] [awk] [bash] [c] [c++] [linux] [sh] [shell]
```

Generally there are 10-30 questions that are "Active" within the list with another 10-20 older questions grouped at the bottom waiting for answers.

There are only four (4) questions total currently shown. Today may just be an incredibly slow day (though even in the middle of summer there were 5x more questions than I see today).

Has there been a change in what, or how long, questions are shown on the "Top Questions" list in the past day or so?

Comment: Summer in the [Northern Hemisphere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Northern_Hemisphere#Noun) or [Southern Hemisphere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Southern_Hemisphere#Noun)?